# Spring Rest entity filed type conversion

Tags: java, spring, rest

My simplified model class Ticket looks like:

```
private String ticketNumber;
private String description;
private String detailedDescription;
private Integer status;
```

My intention is to return to the client a string representation of a status value. So the response looks like that:

```
{
    ticketNumber : "T00001",
    description : "description of a ticket",
    detailedDescription : "description of a ticket",
    status : "Active"
}
```

istead of:

```
{
    ticketNumber : "T00001",
    description : "description of a ticket",
    detailedDescription : "description of a ticket",
    status : 2
}
```

The mapping between integer and a string could be represented as an enum.
But the problem is I don't know where an how I can make the conversion.
One of the solutions could be as described: http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

I just need to convert only one field (and just for GET method) and wondering if there is any simpler solution than creating a new dto class.

Comment: You would use a Ticket to TicketDto converter. The Ticket object represents the object as it is in the DB. The TicketDto represents the object as the client should view it. Your service would return a ticket, and then your web controller or whatever endpoint returns that Ticket converted to a TicketDto.

Comment: You could use a static Map in your object class to store all the mappings. Then create a function to return the string value from the integer utilizing the map.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a JSON message converter.  [JacksonMapper](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)  My preference is GSON.  Spring should automatically add the message converter if you include the library in your classpath.

To use GSON, you will need to register a GSON bean.
Create a config class that returns it:

```
@Configuration
class GsonConfig {
     @Bean
     Gson gson() { return new GsonBuilder().create(); }
}
```

Now Spring should use the gson object you created to convert object to json when the request mapping method in a controller is annotated with @ResponseBody or use a @RestController

To answer your original question, you need to make a type adapter for gson so it knows how to convert the object.
You will need to alter the gson method to look like this:

```
@Bean
Gson gson() {
     new GsonBuilder()
         .registerTypeAdapter(Ticket.class, new JsonSerializer() {
             public JsonElement serialize(Ticket ticket, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                JsonObject o = new JsonObject();
                o.addProperty("ticketNumber", ticket.getTicketNumber());
                o.addProperty("description", ticket.getDescription());
                o.addProperty("detailedDescritpion", ticket.getDetailedDescription());
                String statusAsString;
                  //Covert status to string
                o.addProperty("status", statusAsString);
                return o;
             }
     }).create();
}
```

(I didn't compile this...  Sorry for any syntax errors and typos)

Answer (score 0):

Declare you status/id as an enum.

@JsonValue indicates a single method that should be used to serialize the entire instance.

For example in an enum – we annotate the getName with @JsonValue so that any such entity is serialized via its name:

```
public enum TypeEnumWithValue {
    2("Active"), 1("Closed");

    private String name;

    TypeEnumWithValue(String name) { // Constructor
        this.name= name;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And your Ticket class should have setters/getters for TypeEnumWithValue. When TypeEnumWithValue will be returned, it will return Name in the response instead of 1, 2. I did not compile this code, but hoefully it will work.